# Некорректно работает двунаправленный список

Tags: javascript

Не работает кнопка next в обьекте. Как исправить?

```
function DoubleLinkedList() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.head = {};
}

DoubleLinkedList.prototype = {

    add: function(value) {
             var node = {
                 value: value,
                 next: null,
                 prev: null
             };

             if (this.length == 0) {
                 this.head[this.length] = node;
             }
             else {
                 this.head.next = node;
                 node.prev = this.head[this.length - 1];
                 this.head[this.length] = node;
             }
             this.length++;
        },
```

Comment: в приведенном коде - нет кнопки _next_

Comment: вообще наверное стоит добавить поле _cur_ указывающее на текущее положение в списке

Comment: еще одна ошибка - вы пытаетесь использовать объект, как массив - не надо так :)

Answer (score 1):

Привет.

попробуй так

```
function DoubleLinkedList() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.head;
    this.tail;
}

DoubleLinkedList.prototype = {

    add: function(value) {
             var node = {
                 value: value
             };

             if (this.length == 0) {
                 this.head = node;
                 this.tail = node;
             } else {
                 this.tail.next = node;
                 node.prev = this.tail;
                 this.tail = node;
             }

             this.length++;
        },
```

Comment: возможно стоит добавить описание, что именно вы поменяли и почему теперь работает :)